# Get matched substrings by regular expression

Tags: c#

I am having a regular expression question like this,

giving a input string like `NAMEtony smithNUMBER100ADDRESSLAS vegas`,

the input string has multiple fields marked by `NAME, NUMBER, ADDRESS`, and these fields can be optional and the order is not fixed.
(it can be `ADDRESSLAS vegasNAMEtony smithNUMBER100, or NUMBER100NAMEtony smith`),

I was trying to use regular expression

```
(NAME([A-Za-z0-9\s]{1,}))?(NUMBER(([A-Za-z0-9\s]{1,}))?(ADDRESS([A-Za-z0-9\s]{1,}))?
```

to get the matched, but it doesn't work. Anyone can help?

Comment: This looks like a terrible way of encoding data.  Have you ever used [JSON](https://www.json.org/)?

Comment: I didn't do the encoding, I had this question and was trying to come up some solution. It turns out quite challenging to use regular expression to handle situation like this. Other than regular expression, any other solution to fetch individual field?

Comment: I would suggest writing a function to parse the encoded data.  Your parse function should return an object with properties like `address`, `name`, and `number`.  Then, your extraction of individual properties is as simple as `parse(data).address`, `parse(data).name`, and `parse(data).number`.

Comment: Exactly what result do you expect? Do you want to get name, number and address in this exact order for any such string? Is it guaranteed that there is at most one occurrence of each field in the string?

Answer (score 0):

From your regex it seems you can't have `<` and `>` in your data.
It allows you to make your data much more easily parseable:

```
var text = "NAMEtony smithNUMBER100ADDRESSLAS vegas";
var escapedText =
    text.Replace("ADDRESS", "<ADDRESS>")
        .Replace("NAME", "<NAME>")
        .Replace("NUMBER", "<NUMBER>");
var dataFields = escapedText.Split('<'); // Now you have strings which look like "NAME>...."
foreach (var dataField in dataFields) {
    if (dataField == "") // Somehow handle empty string in the beginning
        continue;
    var splitted = dataField.Split('>');
    string field = splitted[0], data = splitted[1];

    switch (field) {
    case "NAME": ...
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on all three cases of the input string.

Pros: quite a simple regular expression.
Cons: manually setting values to variables in the `if` statement.

```
var input = "NAMEtony smithNUMBER100ADDRESSLAS vegas";
//var input = "ADDRESSLAS vegasNAMEtony smithNUMBER100";
//var input = "NUMBER100NAMEtony smith";

var pattern = "(?'field'NAME|NUMBER|ADDRESS)(?'value'.+?)(?=NAME|NUMBER|ADDRESS|$)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

string name = null;
string number = null;
string address = null;

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    var field = m.Groups["field"].Value;
    var value = m.Groups["value"].Value;

    if (field == "NAME")
        name = value;
    else if (field == "NUMBER")
        number = value;
    else if (field == "ADDRESS")
        address = value;
}
Console.WriteLine(name);
Console.WriteLine(number);
Console.WriteLine(address);
```